# AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only when trying to append dataframe to existing excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to append my dataframe to an existing excel sheet and I went the ExcelWriter overlay route. Here's my full application code:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# import excel file and create dataframe
poam = pd.read_excel('finalpoam.xlsm', header = 4)
new_poam = poam[["POAM ID", "Weakness Source Identifier", "Asset Identifier", "Weakness Name", "Weakness Detector Source", "Original Risk Rating", "Original Detection Date", "Weakness Description", "Overall Remediation Plan", "False Positive"]]

# variables
oracle = "oracle mysql"
sev = "moderate"
og_date = "2022-11"
false = "No"
filename = "finaldr.xlsx"

# alter dataframe
oracle_df = new_poam[new_poam['Weakness Name'].str.contains(oracle, case=False, na=False)]
moderate_df = oracle_df[oracle_df['Original Risk Rating'].str.contains(sev, case=False, na=False)]
false_df = moderate_df[moderate_df['False Positive'].str.contains(false, case=False, na=False)]
final_df = false_df.drop(labels=range(783, 788), axis=0)
final_df = final_df.drop(columns="False Positive")


# append dataframe to existing excel sheet "DR Sheet" in the "finaldr.xlsx" file
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    final_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="DR Sheet", header=None)
```

Doing so gives me this error

```
AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only
```

I tried looking through other posts and the solutions are confusing me- I see some solutions mention a specific cell as the "merge cell" but I have no idea what the merge cell for me is or how to find that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone see's this, luckily my fix was fairly simple: all I had to do was specify the starting row (the row where my appending DataFrame will start from) and it solved the error. Here's my code with the appropriate solution, the `startrow=0` argument was added to the `.to_excel()` function:

**Solution**

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    final_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="DR Sheet", startrow=456, header=None)
```

Here's more info on the **[.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)** function and other inputs you can use.